# Issue with converting R script into Shiny app

Tags: histogram, shinyapps, stochastic

I need your support converting this R script into a Shiny app. Been trying for quite sometime but I'm always getting errors. The code is to apply stochastic modeling in business valuation.

The inputs are:

1. the number of desired simulations i.e. lapply (1:10000) ,
2. Sales volume ,
3. Selling price,
4. Unit cost,
5. Fixed costs,

The outputs are:

1. Net profit (= SalesVolume * (SellingPrice - unitcost) - fixedcosts)
2. a histogram for Net profit

The script is:

```
mydata <- lapply(1:10000, function(i) {

DU <- sample(x= 1:3, size = 1, replace = T)
if(DU==1) {
  SalesVolume= 100000
  SellingPrice= 8
  
}
if(DU==2) {
  SalesVolume= 75000
  SellingPrice= 10
  
}

if(DU==3) {
  SalesVolume= 50000
  SellingPrice= 11
}

unitcost <- rtriangle(1,5.5,7.5)

fixedcosts <- 120000

NetProfit <- SalesVolume * (SellingPrice - unitcost) - fixedcosts

})


NetProfit <- unlist(mydata)

summary(NetProfit)

par(mfrow= c(1,1))

hist(NetProfit)
```

Comment: Hi Sam and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks! Below is my latest attempt. I'm hitting a wall at this and can't get past this stage even to do the histogram. Getting all sort of errors i.e., unused argument (Ui = Ui).

Comment: ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput('UnitCost', 'insert unit cost', value = 0),
    numericInput('SalesVolume', 'insert sales volume', value = 0),
    numericInput('SellingPrice', 'insert selling price', value = 0),
    numericInput('FixedCosts', 'insert fixed cost', value = 0),
    
      textOutput('NetProfit')
      
    
  
  
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$NetProfit <- renderText({
    
   paste(input$SalesVolume * (input$SellingPrice - input$UnitCost) - input$FixedCosts)
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)